# How to make a CvSeq of doubles in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I'd like to make a CvSeq of double's. I thought maybe I could get away with this by specifying the element type as CV_32FC1:

```
MySeq=cvCreateSeq(CV_32FC1,sizeof(CvSeq),sizeof(double),myMemStorage);
```

However, at runtime I it complains:

> Incorrect size of input array (Specified element size doesn't match to the size of the specified element type (try to use 0 for element type) in function cvCreateSeq.

Is there a type e.g. CV_64DC1 in openCV ?

I assume not, but thought its worth asking. At worst I will use 0.

---

@jeff7 answered correctly in the comments, there is a CV_64FC1 value as well as a CvPoint2D64f.

Comment: Is myMemStorage a CV_32FC1 TYPE?

Comment: @jeff7 Yes. Does that exist? I couldn't find it in the O'reilly book.

Comment: i guess I should have just tried that. ok. hold on. let me try it.

Comment: You were right! Thanks. If you fill out an answer I will give you your earned 15 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenCV, a `double` is represented by the type `CV_64FC1` while a `float` is represented by `CV_32FC1`.